# Error Using two objects A1 and A2 of class A as parameters of function on object B1 of class B: B1 not updating attributes?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

**Still Unsolved - the issue lies in the paralaxtrace2 method, in updating the Ray object between propagating through both lenses**

I'm trying to build a Raytracer with Python using two different classes: sphericalrefraction (containing plane, convex and concave lenses) and outputplane (containing just one infinitely large plane), inheriting from one class Optical. Under each of these classes, there are methods intercept (to calculate where a ray with a given direction and point intersects with the lens), and refract (calculating the new direction vector of the ray using the most recent direction vector of the ray). They also have propagate_ray methods in each of the optical elements that appends the newest point to the ray as the intercept() point, and the newest direction as the refract() direction.The ray merely has 1d arrays with x,y,z elements, one for point and one for direction e.g.

```
class Ray:

    def __init__(self, p = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], k = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]):
        self._points = [np.array(p)]
        self._directions = [np.array(k)/np.sqrt(sum(n**2 for n in k))]
        self.checklength()

    def p(self):
        return self._points[len(self._points)-1]

    def k(self):
        return self._directions[len(self._directions)-1]

class SphericalRefraction(OpticalElement):

    def __init__(self, z0 = 0.0, c = 0.0, n1 = 1.0, n2 = 1.0, ar = 0.0):
        self.z0 = z0
        self.c = c
        self.n1 = n1
        self.n2 = n2
        self.ar = ar
        self.R = self.radius()
        self.s = self.surface()
        self.centre = self.centre()

    def intercept(self, ray):
        ar_z = np.sqrt(self.R**2 - self.ar**2) 
        #ar_z = distance from aperture radius z intercept to centre of sphere
        r = ray.p() - self.centre
        r_mag = np.sqrt(sum(n**2 for n in r))
        rdotk = np.dot(r, ray.k())

        if (rdotk**2 - r_mag**2 + self.R**2) < 0:
            return None
        else:
            l1 = -rdotk + np.sqrt(rdotk**2 - r_mag**2 + self.R**2)
            l2 = -rdotk - np.sqrt(rdotk**2 - r_mag**2 + self.R**2)
            lplane = (self.z0 - ray.p()[2]) / ray.k()[2]

        if self.s == "convex":
            if (rdotk**2 - r_mag**2 + self.R**2) == 0:
                if self.centre[2] - ar_z >= (ray.p() + -rdotk*ray.k())[2]:
                    return ray.p() + -rdotk*ray.k()

    def refract(self, ray):
        n_unit = self.unitsurfacenormal(ray)
        k1 = ray.k() 
        ref = self.n1/self.n2
        ndotk1 = np.dot(n_unit, k1)
        if np.sin(np.arccos(ndotk1)) > (1/ref):
            return None
        else:   
            return ref*k1 - (ref*ndotk1 - np.sqrt(1- (ref**2)*(1-ndotk1**2)))*n_unit

    def propagate_ray(self, ray):
        if self.intercept(ray) is None or self.refract(ray) is None:
            return "Terminated"
        else:
            p = self.intercept(ray)
            k2 = self.refract(ray)
            ray.append(p, k2)
            return "Final Point: %s" %(ray.p()) + " and Final Direction: %s" %(ray.k())
```

When I pass two rays through 1 sphericalrefraction and one output plane, I use this method:

def paralaxtrace(self, Ray, SphericalRefraction, OutputPlane):
    SphericalRefraction.propagate_ray(self)
    SphericalRefraction.propagate_ray(Ray)
    OutputPlane.propagate_ray(self)
    OutputPlane.propagate_ray(Ray)
    self.plotparalax(Ray)

I get a graph looking like this, for example:
[image: Using Rays with initial points [+/0.1, +/0.2, 0] and direction [0,0,1] and convex surface SphericalRefraction(50, .02, 1, 1.5168, 49.749)]

I've implemented this method to put it through two sphericalrefraction objects and one output plane, and for some reason it doesn't update between the sphericalrefraction elements?

```
def paralaxtrace2(self, Ray, sr1, sr2, OutputPlane):
    sr1.propagate_ray(self)
    sr1.propagate_ray(Ray)
    sr2.propagate_ray(self)
    sr2.propagate_ray(Ray)
    OutputPlane.propagate_ray(self)
    OutputPlane.propagate_ray(Ray)
    self.plotparalax(Ray)
```

As you can see, the intercept/refract methods always use ray.p() so the newest point, but for some reason it doesn't actually append the new point/direction upon intersecting and refracting with the second spherical element? The graph looks exactly the same as the above one.

Am I passing objects wrongly? Is there another issue? If you need more of my code, please let me know, as I've put in the bare minimum to understand this issue.

**Edit:**

In the console:

```
>> import raytracer as rt
>> lense1 = rt.SphericalRefraction(50, .02, 1, 1.5168, 49.749)
>> lense2 = rt.SphericalRefraction(60, .02, 1, 1.5168, 49.749)
>> ray = rt.Ray([.1,.2,0],[0,0,1])
>> ray.paralaxtrace2(rt.Ray([-0.1, -0.2, 0],[0,0,1]), lense1, lense2, rt.OutputPlane(100))

x, y of 'ray' = [0.0, 50.000500002500019, 100.0] [0.20000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001,   -0.13186017048586818]
x, y of passed ray: [0.0, 50.000500002500019, 100.0] [-0.20000000000000001, -0.20000000000000001, 0.13186017048586818]
```

For this, I get the graph above. What it should do, is since the second convex lens is at 60, it should converge the rays even more. Instead it looks like nothing happens.

**Edit 2:**

The issue doesn't seem to be the mutable default argument in the ray; I still get the same error. For some reason, it has more to do with adding another lens into the function as an argument. Between the propagation in each lens, it doesn't update the coordinates. Does this have to do with a mutable default argument error in the lens' class?

Comment: Less code would be better than more. Can you create a toy example that just demonstrates the object / parameter / attribute interaction that doesn't work like you expect it to?

Comment: I can't really understand this code (for instance, I don't understand why you are passing the `Ray` and `OutputPlane` classes as parameters to `paralaxtrace2`), but the use of default mutable arguments in `Ray.__init__` is always a red flag: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for a good explanation.

Comment: +1 for @DanielRoseman's hunch about mutable default arguments being the cause for your issue.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman - as I'm quite new at Python, I'm finding it a bit difficult to understand how exactly it is affecting my problem. Surely then I would get errors even with only one lens passed through?

Comment: @LukasGraf I added an example, is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Annika not exactly. What I meant is a heavily simplified example with classes that have nothing to do with raytracing, but instead just demonstrate in Python what you described in the title of the question - that's not to say the usage example you added is not helpful.

Comment: No, because the issue is that the default is shared, so that subsequent instances will be affected by previous ones.

Comment: @DanielRoseman how do I fix this with respect to my code? I'm not really sure I understand. I tried to add ray = None above the function in the class, and then as a non default parameter add ray=Ray but this threw me the error that 'Ray isn't defined'?

Answer (score 0):

In order to demonstrate the mutable default argument problem, see this example:

```
class Ray(object):
    def __init__(self, p = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]):
        self.p = p


ray1 = Ray()
ray2 = Ray()

ray1.p.append('appended to ray1.p')
ray2.p.append('appended to ray2.p')

print ray1.p
print ray2.p
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'appended to ray1.p', 'appended to ray2.p']
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'appended to ray1.p', 'appended to ray2.p']
```

(Why are **both** strings seemingly appended to **both** lists?)

Does this surprising behavior match the behavior you're seeing? If so, [mutable default arguments](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) are actually the root of your problem.

Short explanation:
The assignment `p = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` is not evaluated at object construction time (when `__init__` is called), but instead once, at declaration time. Therefore `p` refers to the same list (initially `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`) for all instances of that class, and if you change one, all the others will change as well.

The way to avoid this is to use `None` (or a different, immutable marker value) as your default argument and set the actual default in `__init__`:

```
class Ray(object):
    def __init__(self, p=None):
        if p is None:
            p = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        self.p = p
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but the same issue remains. I don't think it has to do with the original value, since the issue more lies in having two lens objects in the tracing function than in the ray itself...